# What is the best way to test activeadmin classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeadmin

I have simple activeadmin class that looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  actions :index

  index do
    index_columns
  end

  csv do
    index_columns
  end

  def index_columns
    column "Id" do |sp|
      sp.id
    end
  end
end
```

How will be the best to test this code? Write some integrations specs with capybara or maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

General idea behind testing gem's functionality - **you don't test it**.

Gems are (usually) already tested.

Comment: You DO test your own custom configuration. You write something using active admin dsl and each time it's different, so you test exactly that. Especially when you have custom logic in controller.

Comment: @Fedcomp I think you'll benefit from thinking about what I wrote. I'll go again: **You DO NOT test gems PERIOD :)** You test your logic (hopefully), but it has nothing to do with gems. Testing gems classes means messing with gem's internals - it is sooo bad idea to do.

Comment: Testing your OWN logic (which is basically any use of dsl) means YOUR functionality won't break. "period"

Comment: @Fedcomp can you show me, where our opinions differ? I write tests and deem it to be good, how does your last comment applies to downvote and where did you see I said `don't test`?

Comment: You clearly saw first post and saw it has some dsl. And then you suggest to not test it. I suggest to test any use of special dsl where it may break. If i define "i want csv with users to be exported" then i have to put test to be sure that functionality is actually activated.

Comment: @Fedcomp but man, testing functionality and testing active_admin gem - different things. active_admin already shipped with bunch of tests that cover everything. Of course, you **should** test your csv export. But test **should not** rely on whether you've user this or that gem for it, but rather on whether csv export **works**. And if we agree on that, it has nothing to do with testing gem itself

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrey, but needed to do this for work. Here's how I tested the csv portion.

```
  @csv_doc = StringIO.new      

  allow_any_instance_of(ActiveAdmin::ResourceController).to receive(:stream_resource) do |aa_controller|
    receiver = []
    # it's ok to mock this because it's literally their code: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/streaming.rb#L38
    aa_controller.class.active_admin_config.csv_builder.build(aa_controller, receiver)
    receiver.each do |fees_as_csv|
      @csv_doc << fees_as_csv
    end
  end


  @csv_doc.rewind
  csv_string = @csv_doc.readlines.join
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true).map(&:to_hash)

  expect(csv[0]["FIGURING THIS OUT"]).to eq "SUCKED"
```